# How do I install makehuman in windows 8.1?

Tags: makehuman

I downloaded these files;blendertools-1.1.0-all.zip, makehuman-1.1.0-win32.zip and mhx2-stable-025.zip, copied and pasted the three blendertools folders and the mhx2 import folder into the blender addons folder but when I open blender, makehuman addon is not appearing in the the preferrences. please help.
  Thank you

Comment: MakeHuman is a standalone application not related with Blender, you must uncompressed the downloaded zip file and run the executable inside. Only the import addon must be installed, and I believe Blender already ships with one by default, all you have to do is activate it in the user preferences

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about Makehuman, not Blender.